# Как сделать овальную форму подписки?

Tags: html, jquery, css, html5, css3

Как сделать форму подписки такого плана?!

[image: Форма]

Как видно из фото, есть прозрачность. Может это готовый элемент? Тогда дайте ссылку на библиотеку, или же напишите как сделать такое самостоятельно?! Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Закругления: `border-radius: NNpx;`

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

*{box-sizing: border-box; }

form{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="text"] {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  outline: none;
}

/* ---- Placeholder ---- */
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #000;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #000;  
}
::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #000;  
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #000;  
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="email adress">
  <input type="submit" value="sign up">
</form>
```

Comment: Там же граница белого `1px` :)

Comment: Тип инпута можно указывать без самого слова input. Иначе вы повышаете специфичность селектора

Comment: Принцип я понял, спасибо. Ещё 2 вопроса: placeholder не видно из-за прозрачности, чем заменить его?! И как сделать чтобы ввод текста начинался не от края инпута, а с небольшим отступом?

Comment: @Денис, можно задать стили placeholder, а можно задать value у инпута. Отступы регулируйте - padding. А вообще почитайте о формах, их стилизации https://webref.ru/layout/html5-css3/form , https://webref.ru/course/html-content/forms